# Creating a terminal-based text editor with Python

Tags: python, operating-system

I'm making a little operating system in python called 'nangoOS'. I'm currently working on my first app for the 'os' but It doesn't wek how I want it to. I want to print out "--WRITER--" at the top(which I haven't implemented yet), I also want to clear the screen when I open, and exit the app, and lastly I wan't to show the contents of whichever file I'm editing with the app.
This is my current code:

```
# WRITER - Simple Text Editor

import os

def write_file(file_name):
    lines = []
    while True:
        line = input()
        if line == ":q":
            with open(file_name, 'w') as file:
                file.write('\n'.join(lines))
            print(f"File '{file_name}' saved and closed.")
            break
        elif line == ":s":
            with open(file_name, 'w') as file:
                file.write('\n'.join(lines))
            print(f"File '{file_name}' saved.")
        elif line == ":x":
            print(f"File '{file_name}' not saved.")
            break
        else:
            lines.append(line)

def open_writer(file_name):
    os.system("cls")
    print(f"Opening file: '{file_name}'")
    if os.path.isfile(file_name):
        with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
            contents = file.read().rstrip()
        os.system("cls")  # Clear the screen
        print(f"Contents of '{file_name}':")
        print(contents)
    else:
        print(f"Creating new file: '{file_name}'")

    print(f"Enter text for '{file_name}'. Type:\n':q' to quit and save,\n':s' to save,\n':x' to quit without saving.")
    write_file(file_name)
    os.system("cls")  # Clear the screen

if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_name = input("Enter file name: ")
    open_writer(file_name)
```

Can anyone help me?

I tried using chatGPT since that's what has gotten me through a lot of making this, although it doesn't provide the code which gives the desired output.
Here's the output I'm getting along with the steps that I took to get that output:

```
# D:\nangoOS cd DocumentsChanged directory to: D:\nangoOS\DocumentsD:\nangoOS\Documents write # tester.txtHello, World!How are you?:qFile 'tester.txt' saved and closed.D:\nangoOS\Documents read # tester.txtContents of tester.txt:

# Hello, World!How are you?D:\nangoOS\Documents write tester.txt:xFile 'tester.txt' not # saved.D:\nangoOS\Documents
```

also at the end of the file paths there are actiallt backslash amd grater than sign.

Comment: Please give your question a more specific title. Practically all questions are asking for help troubleshooting something that doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Don't waste your time with ChatGPT. It doesn't know how to program any better than you do. Unless there's a web page about this exact problem, it will never be able to figure it out.

Comment: Is your output really all on one line? Where is the input?

Comment: Where is the `Enter file name:` prompt in the output you show? I don't see anything in your code in that sample output.

Comment: Get rid of all the clear screens until you have the main function working, so you can copy and paste everything.